# Notepad problem in delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-5

hi  we are using the Delphi 5 version. We are getting problem while opening the notepad in delphi. We want to open notepad on a button click and pass the data to it so that notepad can display that data. I dont want to save it. please help me regarding this. thanks.

Comment: are you trying to open notepad application or simple txt file?

Comment: I want to open notepad application so that we can save the notepad data depending upon the user. thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can just write a little form with a TMemo on it and drop Notepad?

Comment: @naren A TMemo with alClient, inside a TForm, is pretty much identical to Notepad, and you get way more control.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
uses
  Clipbrd;

procedure LaunchNotepad(const Text: string);
var
  SInfo: TStartupInfo;
  PInfo: TProcessInformation;
  Notepad: HWND;
  NoteEdit: HWND;
  ThreadInfo: TGUIThreadInfo;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@SInfo, SizeOf(SInfo));
  SInfo.cb := SizeOf(SInfo);
  ZeroMemory(@PInfo, SizeOf(PInfo));
  CreateProcess(nil, PChar('Notepad'), nil, nil, False,
                NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, nil, nil, sInfo, pInfo);
  WaitForInputIdle(pInfo.hProcess, 5000);

  Notepad := FindWindow('Notepad', nil);
  // or be a little more strict about the instance found
//  Notepad := FindWindow('Notepad', 'Untitled - Notepad');

  if Bool(Notepad) then begin
    NoteEdit := FindWindowEx(Notepad, 0, 'Edit', nil);
    if Bool(NoteEdit) then begin
      SendMessage(NoteEdit, WM_SETTEXT, 0, Longint(Text));

      // To force user is to be asked if changes should be saved
      // when closing the instance
      SendMessage(NoteEdit, EM_SETMODIFY, WPARAM(True), 0);
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    ZeroMemory(@ThreadInfo, SizeOf(ThreadInfo));
    ThreadInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(ThreadInfo);
    if GetGUIThreadInfo(0, ThreadInfo) then begin
      NoteEdit := ThreadInfo.hwndFocus;
      if Bool(NoteEdit) then begin
        Clipboard.AsText := Text;
        SendMessage(NoteEdit, WM_PASTE, 0, 0);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  LaunchNotepad('test string');
end;
```

Comment: +1 for providing an answer passing the text to Notepad without saving it to file, just as the OP requested.

Comment: +1 for WaitForInputIdle. I Edited your answer to satisfy users (like me) having installed a customized notepad like Notepad2, Notepad++, etc... Though I couldn't get it working via WM_SETTEXT due to unicode problems, so I used the Clipboard.

Comment: @NGLN - Trying to find the (active) edit window for a bunch of text editing programs wouldn't be fun, so the clipboard is probably the best bet for alternative notepad cases. There can be other problems though, for instance I have "remember current session for next launch" in notepad++, so it never opens an empty document at launch.. Anyway, thanks for the edit and also for not *newline*ing my 'begin's. :)

Comment: @Sertac Yeah, and I really wondered how you would like the `end else begin` syntax. ;)

Comment: @Sertac Well - after reading your comment again -, finding the active window seems not to be a problem with GetGUITreadInfo, but the reason I used the clipboard was that sending WM_SETTEXT resulted in only inserting the first character to the Notepad* edit control, which I translated in being an unicode problem.

Comment: @NGLN - It indeed looks like a unicode incompatibility but which side have the error? I can have the same fault by sending a wide string to the regular notepad by using `SendMessageA`, or can send garbled text by sending ansi string with `SendMessageW`. I can set the texts of Notepad (unicode), ConTEXT (ansi) either with SendMessageA or SendMessageW, as long as I use appropriate string type.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I would add the advice of not using Notepad in the first place. Some arguments: hijacking the clipboard may seem innocent but I hate when applications don't warn me about it, and depending on an external application may have some issues, even with a supposedly universal one like Notepad.  (semi-related: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/01/28/9954432.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command in the button click event. Specify the filename which you want to open in the `textFileName.txt`

`ShellExecute(Handle,'open', 'c:\windows\notepad.exe','textFileName.txt', nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL) ;`

If you want to open a blank txt file and don't want to save any data you can use the following method on your click event.
 `ShellExecute(Handle,'open', 'c:\windows\notepad.exe',nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL) ;`

Add `ShellApi` in the uses class also.

**Updated Code**

```
    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
    tempString : TStringList;
    begin
      tempString := TStringList.Create;
      try
        tempString.Add('The text you wanted to display');
        tempString.SaveToFile('C:\~tempFile.txt');
      finally
        tempString.Free;
      end;
      ShellExecute(Handle,'open', 'c:\windows\notepad.exe','C:\~tempFile.txt', nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL) ;
    end;
```

Comment: actually dont want to saved file. I want to pass data to notepad through delphi and save that data from notepad. thanks.

Comment: You want to open the notepad application and the user will type something on it but not necessarily save the data. am I correct?

Comment: No actually I have a string data which i want to display in notepad. After its open in notepad, User will decide about saving that file or not. thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want them to be able to save the data, it would be more sensible to make your own Notepad lookalike, after all, thats what TMemo is good for, and then only allow them to edit the text - if thats your requirement.  Otherwise, very little will stop them saving the file.

Answer (score 0):

NotePad in Delphi.

1. Take one `TMemo` & give name as : (memNotepad)
2. Take one `TrzOpenDialog` (rzopdlgOpenDialog)
3. Take one `TrzSaveDialog` (rzsvdlgSaveDialog)
4. Take one `FontDialog` (ftdlgFontDialog)
5. Take one `TMainMenu` (mmMainMenu)

   - add the menu items File : New,Open,Save,SaveAs,Exit,
                       Edit : Cut,Copy,Paste,Font

**Code :**

```
********************************************************************
unit ufrmNotePad;

interface

uses

  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, Menus, RzShellDialogs, cxGraphics, cxCustomData,
  cxStyles, cxTL, cxControls, cxInplaceContainer, IniFiles;

type
  TfrmNotepad = class(TForm)

    memNotePad: TMemo;
    rzopdlgOpenDialog: TRzOpenDialog;
    rzsvdlgSaveDialog: TRzSaveDialog;
    mmMainMenu: TMainMenu;
    mniFile: TMenuItem;
    mniSave: TMenuItem;
    mniOpen: TMenuItem;
    mniNew: TMenuItem;
    mniSaveAs: TMenuItem;
    mniEdit: TMenuItem;
    mniPaste: TMenuItem;
    mniCopy: TMenuItem;
    mniCut: TMenuItem;
    ftdlgFontDialog: TFontDialog;
    mniFont: TMenuItem;
    mniExit: TMenuItem;
    procedure mniOpenClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure mniSaveClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure mniNewClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure mniSaveAsClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure mniCopyClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure mniPasteClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure mniCutClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure mniFontClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure mniEditClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure mniExitClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);

  private

    { Private declarations }
    procedure OpenDialog;
    procedure SaveDialog;
    procedure NewNotepad;
    procedure SaveAS;
    procedure Copy;
    procedure Cut;
    procedure Paste;
    procedure Font;
    procedure SaveSettingInToFile;
    procedure RetrieveSettingFromTheFile;
  public

    { Public declarations }
    FIniFile : TIniFile;
    FFileName : String;
    FCount : Integer;
  end;

var
  frmNotepad : TfrmNotepad;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ Open File from the disk }

{ FCount- helps for save the file, if file is already save then FCount := 1 else FCount := 0}

{ FFileName - helps for store the filename of open filename or saved filename }

procedure TfrmNotepad.OpenDialog;

begin

  FCount := 1;

  rzopdlgOpenDialog.Title := 'Open File';

  rzopdlgOpenDialog.Filter := 'Text Files|*.txt; RTF Files|*.rtf';

  if rzsvdlgSaveDialog.FileName = FFileName then

  begin

    if rzopdlgOpenDialog.Execute then

      memNotePad.Lines.LoadFromFile(rzopdlgOpenDialog.FileName);

  end

  { if any file already opened and without saving the file try to open new file
    then message dialog box appears on the screen for save the file or save modification of the file }

  else if (memNotePad.Modified) then

  begin

    ModalResult := MessageDlg('Do you want to save Changes to untitled?',mtConfirmation,mbYesNoCancel,0);
    if (ModalResult = mrYes) then
    begin
      if rzsvdlgSaveDialog.Execute then
        memNotepad.Lines.SaveToFile(rzsvdlgSaveDialog.FileName + '.txt');
      memNotePad.Clear;
      memNotePad.Modified := False;
    end
    else if (ModalResult = mrNo) then
    begin
      if rzopdlgOpenDialog.Execute then
      begin
        memNotePad.Lines.LoadFromFile(rzopdlgOpenDialog.FileName);
        FFileName := rzopdlgOpenDialog.FileName;
      end;
    end;
  end

  else if rzopdlgOpenDialog.Execute then

  begin

    memNotePad.Lines.LoadFromFile(rzopdlgOpenDialog.FileName);
    FFileName := rzopdlgOpenDialog.FileName;
  end;
  Caption := rzopdlgOpenDialog.FileName + ' - Delphi Notepad';

end;

{ Saving the file }

procedure TfrmNotepad.SaveDialog;

begin

  rzsvdlgSaveDialog.Title := 'Save';

  rzsvdlgSaveDialog.Filter := 'Text Files|*.txt; RTF Files|*.rtf';

  { if file already exist and after modification we try to save then it directly save into the file without opening the save dialog box }

  if FCount = 1 then

  begin

    { filename store in the FFileName is compare with the save dialog box filename
      if it matches then modification dirctly save into that file without opening the save dialog box }

    if rzsvdlgSaveDialog.FileName = FFileName then

      memNotePad.Lines.SaveToFile(rzsvdlgSaveDialog.FileName + '.txt')

    { filename store in the FFileName is compare with the open dialog box filename
      if it matches then modification dirctly save into that file without opening the save dialog box }

    else if rzopdlgOpenDialog.FileName = FFileName then

    begin

      rzsvdlgSaveDialog.FileName := rzopdlgOpenDialog.FileName;
      memNotePad.Lines.SaveToFile(rzsvdlgSaveDialog.FileName);
    end;
  end

  { else file already not save then Save Dialog box open }

  else

  begin

    if rzsvdlgSaveDialog.Execute then
      memNotePad.Lines.SaveToFile(rzsvdlgSaveDialog.FileName + '.txt');
    Caption := rzsvdlgSaveDialog.FileName + ' - Delphi Notepad';
    FCount := 1;
  end;
  FFileName := rzsvdlgSaveDialog.FileName;

end;

{ New Notepad }

procedure TfrmNotepad.NewNotepad;

begin

  if FCount = 1 then

  begin

    memNotePad.Clear;

    Caption := 'UnNamed Delphi Notepad';

  end

  else if not (memNotePad.Modified) then

  begin

    memNotePad.Clear;

    Caption := 'UnNamed Delphi Notepad';

  end

  { without saving the modification's of file if try to click on new then
    message dialog box appears on the screen for saving the modification's }

  else if (memNotePad.Modified) then

  begin

    ModalResult := MessageDlg('Do you want to save Changes',mtConfirmation,mbYesNoCancel,0);

    if (ModalResult = mrYes) then

    begin

      if rzsvdlgSaveDialog.Execute then
        memNotepad.Lines.SaveToFile(rzsvdlgSaveDialog.FileName + '.txt');
      memNotePad.Clear;
      memNotePad.Modified := False;
    end
    else if (ModalResult = mrNo) then
    begin
      memNotePad.Clear;
      memNotePad.Modified := False;
    end;
  end;

  FFileName := rzsvdlgSaveDialog.FileName;

  FCount := 1;

end;

{ Save As }

procedure TfrmNotepad.SaveAS;

begin

  rzsvdlgSaveDialog.Title := 'Save As';

  rzsvdlgSaveDialog.Filter := 'Text Files|*.txt; RTF Files|*.rtf';

  if rzsvdlgSaveDialog.Execute then

    memNotepad.Lines.SaveToFile(rzsvdlgSaveDialog.FileName + '.txt');

  memNotePad.Clear;

  memNotePad.Modified := False;

end;

{ Cut text }

procedure TfrmNotepad.Cut;

begin

  memNotePad.CutToClipboard;

end;

{ Copy text }

procedure TfrmNotepad.Copy;

begin

  memNotePad.CopyToClipboard;

end;

{ Paste }


procedure TfrmNotepad.Paste;

begin

  memNotePad.PasteFromClipboard;

end;

{ Font Dialog is assign to memo }

procedure TfrmNotepad.Font;

begin

  if ftdlgFontDialog.Execute then

    memNotePad.Font := ftdlgFontDialog.Font;

end;


{ Save the setting of font in to Ini file }

procedure TfrmNotepad.SaveSettingInToFile;

var

  LColorName : String;

begin

  FIniFile.WriteString('Setting', 'FontName', memNotePad.Font.Name);

  FIniFile.WriteString('Setting', 'FontSize', IntToStr(memNotePad.Font.Size));

  LColorName := ColorToString(memNotePad.Font.Color);

  FIniFile.WriteString('Setting', 'FontColor', LColorName);

end;


{ Retrieve the setting of font from Ini file }

procedure TfrmNotepad.RetrieveSettingFromTheFile;

var

  LFontName, LFontSize, LFontColor: String;

begin

  FIniFile := TIniFile.Create('FontSettings.ini');

  LFontName := FIniFile.ReadString('Setting', 'FontName', 'Arial');

  memNotePad.Font.Name := LFontName;

  LFontSize := FIniFile.ReadString('Setting', 'FontSize', '8');

  memNotePad.Font.Size := StrToInt(LFontSize);

  LFontColor := FIniFile.ReadString('Setting', 'FontColor', 
ColorToString(clBlack));

  memNotePad.Font.Color := StringToColor(LFonTColor);

  ftdlgFontDialog.Font := memNotePad.Font;

end;

procedure TfrmNotepad.mniOpenClick(Sender: TObject);

begin

  OpenDialog;

end;


procedure TfrmNotepad.mniSaveClick(Sender: TObject);

begin

  SaveDialog;

end;


procedure TfrmNotepad.mniNewClick(Sender: TObject);

begin

  NewNotepad;

end;


procedure TfrmNotepad.mniSaveAsClick(Sender: TObject);

begin

  SaveAS;

end;


{ Exit from Notepad }

procedure TfrmNotepad.mniExitClick(Sender: TObject);

begin

  { While exit if the modification in file is not save then then message dialog appear on the screen }

  if (memNotePad.Modified) then

  begin

    ModalResult := MessageDlg('Do you want to save 
Changes',mtConfirmation,mbYesNoCancel,0);

    if (ModalResult = mrYes) then

    begin

      if rzsvdlgSaveDialog.FileName = FFileName then

        memNotePad.Lines.SaveToFile(rzsvdlgSaveDialog.FileName + '.txt')

      else if rzopdlgOpenDialog.FileName = FFileName then

      begin

        rzsvdlgSaveDialog.FileName := rzopdlgOpenDialog.FileName;

        memNotePad.Lines.SaveToFile(rzsvdlgSaveDialog.FileName);

      end

      else if rzsvdlgSaveDialog.Execute then

        memNotepad.Lines.SaveToFile(rzsvdlgSaveDialog.FileName + '.txt');

      memNotePad.Clear;

      memNotePad.Modified := False;

      Close;

    end

    else if (ModalResult = mrNo) then

    begin

      memNotePad.Clear;

      memNotePad.Modified := False;

      Close;

    end;

  end;

  { call method for saving the font setting into Ini file }

  SaveSettingInToFile;

end;

procedure TfrmNotepad.mniCutClick(Sender: TObject);

begin

  Cut;

end;


procedure TfrmNotepad.mniCopyClick(Sender: TObject);

begin

  Copy;

end;


procedure TfrmNotepad.mniPasteClick(Sender: TObject);

begin

  Paste;

end;


procedure TfrmNotepad.mniFontClick(Sender: TObject);
begin

  Font;

end;


procedure TfrmNotepad.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

begin

  FCount := 0;

  FFileName := 'ok';

  { call method for retrieve the font setting from Ini file }

  RetrieveSettingFromTheFile;

end;


procedure TfrmNotepad.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);

begin

  { call method for saving the font setting into Ini file }

  SaveSettingInToFile;

end;


{ when text is selected on notepad, only then the copy & cut are enabled else disabled }

procedure TfrmNotepad.mniEditClick(Sender: TObject);

begin

  mniCopy.Enabled := memNotePad.SelLength > 0;

  mniCut.Enabled := memNotePad.SelLength > 0;

end;


procedure TfrmNotepad.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);

begin

  { While Destroying the form if the modification in file is not save then then
    message dialog appear on the screen }

  rzsvdlgSaveDialog.Filter := 'Text Files|*.txt; RTF Files|*.rtf';

  if (memNotePad.Modified) then

  begin

    ModalResult := MessageDlg('Do you want to save 
Changes',mtConfirmation,mbYesNoCancel,0);
    if (ModalResult = mrYes) then

    begin

      if rzsvdlgSaveDialog.FileName = FFileName then

        memNotePad.Lines.SaveToFile(rzsvdlgSaveDialog.FileName + '.txt')

      else if rzopdlgOpenDialog.FileName = FFileName then

      begin

        rzsvdlgSaveDialog.FileName := rzopdlgOpenDialog.FileName;

        memNotePad.Lines.SaveToFile(rzsvdlgSaveDialog.FileName);

      end

      else if rzsvdlgSaveDialog.Execute then

        memNotepad.Lines.SaveToFile(rzsvdlgSaveDialog.FileName + '.txt');

      memNotePad.Clear;

      memNotePad.Modified := False;

    end

    else if (ModalResult = mrNo) then

    begin

      memNotePad.Clear;

      memNotePad.Modified := False;

    end;

  end;

  CanClose := True;

end;


end.
```